# Numerical integration of a 2D advection equation with spacially varying coefficients.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am interested in a simple algorithm for solving this PDE for $f(x,y,t)$:

$$f_t + A y  f_x - B x  f_y =0$$

With $A,B>0$. The initial condition is some arbitrary smooth function (probably gonna use a gaussian) $$f(x,y,0)=g(x,y)$$

And $f$ vanishes at infinity.

I have very little experience in numerical methods for PDEs. I am interested in learning a simple (as simple as possible without being hopelessly inaccurate!) algorithm on how to deal with such a problem. I imagine I will be discretizing both time and the spacial variables and then replacing the derivatives with their approximations.

The Lax-Wendorff method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Wendroff_method) has been suggested to me, but I can't find any entry-level materials on this, and don't even see how to apply it here (i.e. how to transform what I have into the general form).

From what I've managed to find out, I will need to form some sort of grid for time and position. But first I would probably want to introduce dimensionless variables to replace $x,y$. Then, I will need to choose an appropriate step in the space variables and time (how do I know what to pick, so that my solution is stable?). And finally, I will be needing some sort of time step scheme, in the form

$$f^{t+1}_{i,j} = F(f^t_{i,j} \ ; \ f^t_{i+1,j} \ ; \ ... \ ; \ f^t_{i-1,j-1})$$

So that the value of the function at some node of the grid depends on its (and all 8 adjacent nodes') values in the previous time step.

In principle, this seems to be to be it, now I just need to find the appropriate discretization and scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest time-stepping method is a FTCS scheme (forward time, centred space).

I will denote $f(x_i,y_j,t_k)$ by $f_{i,j}^k$.

This method is explicit in time, and approximates the time derivative by
$$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right|_{x_i,y_j}^{t_k}=\frac{f_{i,j}^{k+1}-f_{i,j}^{k}}{\Delta t}.$$

The spatial derivatives are approximated by
$$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x_i,y_j}^{t_k}=\frac{f_{i+1,j}^{k}-f_{i-1,j}^{k}}{2\Delta x}$$
and
$$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{x_i,y_j}^{t_k}=\frac{f_{i,j+1}^{k}-f_{i,j-1}^{k}}{2\Delta y}.$$
(Setting $\Delta x=\Delta y$ is probably going to be helpful)

And putting it together, you get
$$\frac{f_{i,j}^{k+1}-f_{i,j}^{k}}{\Delta t}=-Ay_j\frac{f_{i+1,j}^{k}-f_{i-1,j}^{k}}{2\Delta x}+Bx_i\frac{f_{i,j+1}^{k}-f_{i,j-1}^{k}}{2\Delta y},$$
which gives this time-stepping scheme
$$f_{i,j}^{k+1}=f_{i,j}^{k}-\frac{Ay_j\Delta t}{2\Delta x}\left(f_{i+1,j}^{k}-f_{i-1,j}^{k}\right)+\frac{Bx_i\Delta t}{2\Delta y}\left(f_{i,j+1}^{k}-f_{i,j-1}^{k}\right).$$

So you can calculate $f^{k+1}_{i,j}$ using 5 grid points from the $k$-th time step. You need boundary conditions to work out the boundary values of $f$, and initial conditions for $f^0_{i,j}$, and then at each time step just apply the scheme to each interior point.

Stability is tricky in 2D. Basically, keep your spatial steps small, and your time step s smaller, and you should be alright, but because you have $yf_x$ and $xf_y$ terms you will have more problems with stability when $x$ and $y$ are large, so bear that in mind.

I hope this helps, and it should help you implement other schemes of you need higher order convergence.

Comment: I have a problem - when I'm applying the next time step to some grid point, do I change its value immediately in the algorithm, or rather store it in another array, and when I'm calculating the next time step for some adjacent point, still use the old value? I'm guessing the latter, right?

Comment: Generally you'd store your results from all time steps, so you'd have a 3D array for $f$, where the (i,j,k)-th element corresponds to $f(x_i,y_j,t_k)$, and so you wont ever overwrite previously calculated values.

Comment: Why did you use the [1 -1] stencil for the spacial derivatives, rather than the [1 0] ?

Comment: For spatial derivatives with boundary conditions it makes more sense to do it that way, because it means that the boundary condition at each side of the domain is used. When time-stepping we only have an initial condition, so can only rely on information from one side of where we are.